# Como hacer mostrar archivos ya adjuntos

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hola estoy trabajando en React en donde estoy realizando un formulario que se ingresan archivos, luego en otro componente este deberia mostrar los archivos adjuntos pero llevo horas intentando hacer que los muestre para descargarlos.

este es el componente donde se crea el tickets.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Registro } from './Listar';
import Modal from 'react-modal'; // Importa react-modal
import { toast } from 'sonner';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';



interface FormValues {
  operadora: string;
  soporte: string;
  severidad: string;
  solicitante: string;
  breve: string;
  producto: string;
  modulo: string;
  detallada: string;
  ambiente: string;
  nota: string;
  fechaCreacion: string;

}

interface RegistrarProps {
  usu: string;
  opcionesOperadora: string[];
  opcionesSolicitante: string[];
}


interface OpcionesSolicitantesPorOperadora {
  [operadora: string]: string[];
}

const opcionesSolicitantesPorOperadora: OpcionesSolicitantesPorOperadora = {
  Mexico: ["M1", "M2", "M3"],
  Colombia: ["C1", "C2", "C3"],
  Panama: ["P1", "P2", "P3"],
  CostaRica: ["CR1", "CR2", "CR3"],
  // Agrega más operadoras y sus respectivas opciones de solicitantes aquí
};




export const Registrar: React.FC<RegistrarProps> = (props) => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<FormValues>({
    operadora: '',
    soporte: '',
    severidad: '',
    solicitante: '',
    breve: '',
    producto: '',
    modulo: '',
    detallada: '',
    ambiente: '',
    nota: '',
    fechaCreacion: '',
  });


  
  const obtenerRegistros = () => {
    var datos = localStorage.getItem("registroslogin");
    if (datos) {
      return JSON.parse(datos);
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  };
 

  const [fechaCreacion, setFechaCreacion] = useState<string>("");
  const [registroslogin, setRegistrosLogin] = useState(obtenerRegistros());
  const [adjuntoNota, setAdjuntoNota] = useState<string>("");

  const [adjuntos, setAdjuntos] = useState<File[]>([]); // Estado para los archivos adjuntos
 
  const [nuevoId, setNuevoId] = useState<string>(''); // Declara nuevoId como un estado

 

 const [opcionesSolicitante, setOpcionesSolicitantes] = useState<string[]>([]);
 const [mostrarMensaje, setMostrarMensaje] = useState(false);


  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      [id]: value,
    }));
  };
  const [slaTime, setSlaTime] = useState<number>(0); // Inicialmente, el tiempo SLA es cero
  const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState<Date | null>(null); // Inicialmente, la fecha de vencimiento es nula
  
  const handleOperadoraChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setFormValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      operadora: value,
    }));
    setOpcionesSolicitantes(opcionesSolicitantesPorOperadora[value] || []);
  };


  
  const [mostrarModal, setMostrarModal] = useState(false);

  const handleAdjuntosChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const archivos = e.target.files;
    if (archivos) {
      const adjuntosArray = Array.from(archivos);
      console.log('Archivos adjuntos:', adjuntosArray);
      setAdjuntos(adjuntosArray);
    }
  };


  const botonGuardar = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    
    const nuevoIdGenerado = uuidv4()
    setNuevoId(nuevoIdGenerado);
    localStorage.setItem('adjuntos', JSON.stringify(adjuntos));
    console.log('Adjuntos enviados:', adjuntos);
    localStorage.setItem('lastTicketId', nuevoIdGenerado);

    setRegistrosLogin([...registroslogin, { ...formValues, adjuntos, id: nuevoId }]); // Agrega los adjuntos al registro
    if (adjuntos.length > 0) {
      // Aquí puedes manejar la lógica para subir o almacenar los archivos adjuntos
      console.log("Adjuntos:", adjuntos);
    }
    let slaTimeInMilliseconds = 0;
    switch (formValues.severidad) {
      case 'Critical':
        slaTimeInMilliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 horas
        break;
      case 'Alta':
        slaTimeInMilliseconds = 48 *  60 * 60 * 1000; // 48 horas
        break;
      case 'Normal':
        slaTimeInMilliseconds = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 3 días
        break;
      case 'Baja':
        slaTimeInMilliseconds = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 5 días
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    setSlaTime(slaTimeInMilliseconds / 1000);
    // Obtener la fecha y hora actual
  const now = new Date();
  const fechaCreacionFormatted = `${now.toLocaleDateString()} ${now.toLocaleTimeString()}`;

  // Almacenar la fecha y hora de creación en el estado
  setFechaCreacion(fechaCreacionFormatted);
  const dueDate = new Date(now.getTime() + slaTimeInMilliseconds);
  setDueDate(dueDate);


    setMostrarMensaje(true);
    setMostrarModal(true);
    limpiarFormulario();

    const registro = { ...formValues, adjuntos, id: nuevoId, dueDate, fechaCreacion: fechaCreacionFormatted };
  setRegistrosLogin([...registroslogin, registro]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("registroslogin", JSON.stringify(registroslogin));
  }, [registroslogin]);

  const limpiarFormulario = () => {
    setFormValues({
      operadora: "",
      soporte: "",
      severidad: "",
      solicitante: "",
      breve: "",
      producto: "",
      modulo: "",
      detallada: "",
      ambiente: "",
      nota: "",
      fechaCreacion: "",
    });
   

    const form = document.getElementById("miFormulario") as HTMLFormElement;
    if (form) {
      form.reset();
    }
  };

 


  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-50 mt-20 p-20 font-semibold py-4 px-4 rounded">
      <div className="text-3xl mb-10">Formulario De Registro De tickets</div>
      <form id="miFormulario" onSubmit={botonGuardar}>
        <div className="p-20 flex justify-center items-center flex-grow ">
          <div className="w-full h-[450px] bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md " style={{ marginBottom: '0cm' }}>
            {/* Primer cajón */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-4 font-semibold">
              <div className="text-[15px]">Datos Generales</div>
             
            </div>
             <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 mt-6 items-center ">
            <div>
          <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Operadora :       </label>
          
          <select
            className="mt-2 form-select text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
            id="operadora"
            value={formValues.operadora}
            onChange={handleOperadoraChange}
            required
          >
             <option value="">Seleccione</option>
            {props.opcionesOperadora.map((operadora, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={operadora}>
                {operadora}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Tipo de soporte :       </label>
                <select
                  className="form-select text-center"
                  id="soporte"
                  value={formValues.soporte}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                >
                  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                  <option value="Incidencia">Incidencia</option>
                  <option value="Consulta">Consulta</option>
                  <option value="Problema">Problemas</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 mt-16 items-center ">
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Nivel de Severidad:</label>
                <select
                  className="form-select text-center"
                  id="severidad"
                  value={formValues.severidad}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                >
                  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                  <option value="Critica">Critical</option>
                  <option value="Alta">Hight</option>
                  <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                  <option value="Baja">Low</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Ambiente  :            </label>
                <input
                  className=" mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
                  id="ambiente"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Escribir Aqui"
                  value={formValues.ambiente}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 mt-16 items-center flex justify-between">
            <div>
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Solicitante :      </label>
          <select
            className="mt-2 form-select text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
            id="solicitante"
            value={formValues.solicitante}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          >
             <option value="">Seleccione</option>
            {props.opcionesSolicitante.map((solicitante, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={solicitante}>
                {solicitante}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Descripción Breve :     </label>
                <input
                  className=" mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
                  id="breve"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Breve descripción del problema"
                  value={formValues.breve}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className="p-20 flex justify-center items-center  flex justify-between">
          <div className="w-full h-[500px] bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md  " >
            {/* Segundo cajón */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-4 font-semibold">
              <div className="text-[15px]">Descripcion</div>
              
            </div>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 mt-8 items-center">
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Producto :        </label>
                <input
                  className=" mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
                  id="producto"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Nombre del producto"
                  value={formValues.producto}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Módulo Impacto :       </label>
                <input
                  className=" mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
                  id="modulo"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Módulo afectado"
                  value={formValues.modulo}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className="grid gap-8 mt-16">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
    <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Descripción Detallada:</label>
    <textarea
      className="mt-2 form-input w-full h-20 md:w-96 md:h-32 lg:w-120 lg:h-40 xl:w-150 xl:h-48 border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded"
      id="detallada"
      placeholder="Descripción detallada del problema"
      value={formValues.detallada}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      required
      style={{ resize: "none" }} // Esto evita que el usuario pueda redimensionar el cuadro de texto
      
                />
              </div>
            
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>



        
        <div className="p-20 flex justify-center items-center  flex justify-between">
        <div className="w-full h-[650px] bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md  " >
          {/* Tercer cajón */}
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-4 font-semibold">
            <div className="text-[15px]">Archivos</div>
          </div>
          <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 mt-8 items-center">
            <div>
              <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Adjuntar archivos:</label>
              <input
  type="file"
  accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
  multiple // Permite seleccionar múltiples archivos
  onChange={handleAdjuntosChange} // Usar la función para manejar cambios en los archivos
/>
            </div>
            
              <div>
                <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Nota para archivo:     </label>
                <textarea
                  className="mt-2 form-input w-full h-20 md:w-96 md:h-32 lg:w-120 lg:h-40 xl:w-150 xl:h-48 border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded"
                  id="nota"
                  placeholder="explicar documento adjunto"
                  value={formValues.nota}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  style={{ resize: "none" }} 
                />
              </div>
              {adjuntos.length > 0 && (
                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-full mt-30 items-center">
                  <div>
      <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Usuario  :</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
        value={props.usu}
        readOnly
      />
    </div>
                  <div>
                    <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Fecha  :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded "
                      value={new Date().toLocaleString()} // Obtiene la fecha actual y la muestra
                      readOnly
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Archivos Adjuntos  :</label>
                    <ul>
                      {adjuntos.map((adjunto, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>{adjunto.name}</li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      {mostrarMensaje && (
        <div className="bg-green-200 border border-green-600 text-green-800 p-4 mb-4 rounded">
          Ticket creado correctamente. El número de Ticket ID es: {nuevoId}
          <div>
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Fecha de vencimiento del SLA:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="mt-2 form-input text-center border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded"
              value={dueDate ? dueDate.toLocaleString() : ''} // Mostrar la fecha y hora si está definida
              readOnly
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

        <div className="mt-12">
          
        <button
        className="bg-green-600 text-gray-50 font-semibold py-4 px-4 rounded"
      >
        Guardar Datos
      </button>
          
        </div>
        
      </form>
      
    </div>
  );
};
```

y este es el codigo en donde se deberia mostrar el tickets con todos los campos llenados y los archivos adjuntos.

```
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { Registro } from './Listar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';


interface FormularioEdicionProps {
  registro: Registro;
  guardarEdicion: (nuevoRegistro: Registro) => void;
  isOpen: boolean;
  closeModal: () => void;
}

const renderAdjuntos = (adjuntos: (File | string)[]) => {
  return (
    <div className="adjuntos-container">
      <h3>Archivos Adjuntos</h3>
      <ul>
        {adjuntos.map((archivo, idx) => (
          <li key={idx}>
            <a
              href={typeof archivo === 'string' ? archivo : (archivo instanceof File && URL.createObjectURL(archivo)) || undefined}
              download={archivo instanceof File ? archivo.name : `adjunto-${idx}`}
            >
              {typeof archivo === 'string' ? `Descargar Archivo ${idx + 1}` : archivo.name}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};



const FormularioEdicion: React.FC<FormularioEdicionProps> = ({
  registro,
  guardarEdicion,
  isOpen,
  closeModal,
}) => {
  const [mensaje, setMensaje] = useState(registro.nota || ''); 
  const [adjuntos, setAdjuntos] = useState<File[]>(registro.adjuntos || []);

  const handleMensajeChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setMensaje(e.target.value);
  };

  const [adjuntoData, setAdjuntoData] = useState<(File | string)[]>(registro.adjuntos || []);
  const handleAdjuntosChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const archivos = e.target.files; // Obtener archivos desde el evento
        
    if (archivos) {
      const adjuntosArray = Array.from(archivos).filter(file => file instanceof File); // Filtrar solo archivos
      console.log('Archivos adjuntos:', adjuntosArray); // Agregar un log aquí
      setAdjuntoData([...registro.adjuntos, ...adjuntosArray]); // Actualizar el estado con nuevos adjuntos
      setAdjuntos(adjuntosArray); // Almacenar los archivos adjuntos en el estado
    }
  };
  

  const descargarArchivo = (archivo: File | string) => {
    if (archivo instanceof File) {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(archivo);
  
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', archivo.name);
  
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
  
      // Limpiar el enlace y el objeto URL después de la descarga
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    } else if (typeof archivo === 'string') {
      // Tratar el caso cuando el archivo es una URL
      window.open(archivo, '_blank');
    }
  };
  

  
  


  const guardarCambios = () => {
    const notaAnterior = registro.nota || '';
    const adjuntosAnteriores = registro.adjuntos || [];
    const conversacionAnterior = registro.conversacion || [];
    const nuevoMensaje = { nota: mensaje, adjuntos: [...adjuntos] };
    const nuevaConversacion = [...conversacionAnterior, nuevoMensaje];
  
    const nuevoRegistro = {
      ...registro,
      nota: notaAnterior + '\n' + mensaje,
      adjuntos: [...adjuntosAnteriores, ...adjuntos],
      conversacion: nuevaConversacion,
    };
  
    guardarEdicion(nuevoRegistro);
    closeModal();
  };
  

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeModal}
      contentLabel="Responder al Ticket"
    >
      <div className="chat-container">
        <ul className="chat-messages">
        {registro.conversacion &&
  registro.conversacion.map((mensaje, index) => (
    <li key={index} className="chat-message">
      <div className="chat-message-text">{mensaje.nota}</div>
      
      {mensaje.adjuntos && mensaje.adjuntos.length > 0 && (
  <div className="chat-message-attachments">
    <ul>
      {mensaje.adjuntos.map((archivo, idx) => (
        <li key={idx}>
          <a
            href="#"
            onClick={() => descargarArchivo(archivo)}
          >
            Descargar Archivo {idx + 1}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)}


    </li>
  ))}

        </ul>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div className="form-container">
          <div className="mr-10 min-h-10 bg-gray-50 mt-20 p-20 font-semibold py-2 px-2 rounded">
            <div>
              <div className="text-3xl mb-10">Formulario De tickets</div>
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-full p-20 font-semibold py-2 px-2 rounded">
          <div className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md" style={{ marginBottom: '0cm' }}>
             <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Operadora :</label>
             <span>{registro.operadora}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Soporte  :     </label>
            <span>{registro.soporte}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Nivel de Severidad   :     </label>
            <span>{registro.severidad}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Ambiente  :            </label>
            <span>{registro.ambiente}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Solicitante :       </label>
            <span>{registro.solicitante}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Descripción Breve :     </label>
            <span>{registro.breve}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Producto :          </label>
            <span>{registro.producto}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Módulo Impacto :        </label>
            <span>{registro.modulo}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Descripción Detallada :         </label>
            <span>{registro.detallada}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
            <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">nota :         </label>
            <span>{registro.nota}</span>
            <hr className="border border-black w-full mb-4" />
          
          <div className="files-container">
  <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800">Archivo adjunto:</label>
  {renderAdjuntos(adjuntoData)}
</div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div className="mensaje-input">
          <label className="mb-2 text-gray-800 mr-2">Mensaje:</label>
          <textarea
            className="mt-2 form-input w-full h-20 md:w-96 md:h-32 lg:w-120 lg:h-40 xl:w-150 xl:h-48 border border-gray-300 font-semibold py-1 px-1 rounded"
            value={mensaje}
            onChange={handleMensajeChange}
            placeholder="Escribe un mensaje..."
            style={{ resize: 'none' }}
          />
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleAdjuntosChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="btn-container">
          <button
            className="bg-green-600 text-gray-50 font-semibold py-4 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={guardarCambios}
          >
            Enviar
          </button>
          <button
            className="bg-red-600 text-gray-50 font-semibold py-4 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={closeModal}
          >
            Cerrar
          </button>
        </div></div></div>
      </form>
    </Modal>
    
  );
};

export default FormularioEdicion;
```

Porfavor les pido ayuda ya que nose que mas hacer llevo rato haciendo esto y nose porque no se estan mostrando los archivos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No me queda claro.. se ingresan a donde?? es solo una lista de nombres??